# how to access sq-lite database from phone-gap using javacscript

Tags: android, cordova

I need to access data from .sqlite file which is located in **data/data/mypackage/databases/mydb**. mydb is the databse file, Here i want to retrive data from this databse using javascript. How to do this, Any one help me. Is it possible to retrive data from .sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

Web SQL Database API isn't actually part of the HTML5, so just use opendatabase method, 
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

method took following five paramters:

```
Database name
Version number
Text description
Size of database
Creation callback
```

fore more details [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Comment: Here in my code i want to get data from .sqlite database which is created from java code